# Who approves pending edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

After editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12923221/3664960), I looked at the user's profile and thought,

> [My pending] edit won't get approved as the user has been inactive for a long long time.

To my great and pleasant surprise my edit has been approved. So I looked at his profile again to see if by any chance the OP logged in and approved my edit.

Up to this point, I was thinking only the OP can approve or reject edits.

So who approved the edit, and what privilege is required to approve edits to other peoples' questions?

Comment: When you have less than 2k rep, your edit goes into a suggested edit review queue where it is reviewed by a minimum of three users (up to five) with greater than 2k rep have to spend one of their twenty per day review votes to approve or reject your edit. You can find out who reviewed your edit by viewing [the review item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10785200)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not a very good reason to close a question here... There is an abundance of questions on meta that have been brought on by a misunderstanding of how the system works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That would come down to lack of research, which is a reason to _downvote_ but not to _close._ Part of the point of Meta is for people to come here to ask questions (or search for answers) when they're confused about how the site works. This question is not off-topic.

Comment: You've suggested 378 edits. Did you think all of them were approved/rejected by the original poster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suggested edits go into the Suggested Edits Review Queue where any user with full editing privileges (2,000 reputation) can vote to approve or reject the edit. It takes three votes in either direction to finalize the action. The person who posted simply gets unilateral control (their vote is binding and takes immediate effect).

The users who approved your edit can be found on the [review item page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10785200).